# how to install nftables and its dependencies inside docker container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kind

I have a KIND cluster with one control plane and two worker nodes.
On worker node, i want to install and debug nftables.

when i try to list rules, i see below error

```
root@worker:/# nft list ruleset
nft: error while loading shared libraries: libnftables.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When i try to install nftables and its dependencies , i see below error.

```
root@-worker:/# apt-get install nftables
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
nftables is already the newest version (0.9.8-3).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nftables : Depends: libnftables1 (= 0.9.8-3) but it is not installable
            Depends: libedit2 (>= 3.1-20130611-0) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Have you tried with `apt --fix-broken install` ?

Answer (score 1):

Error says nftables are already installed.
Fix your apt packages then try uninstall and install nftables

To fix apt :
apt-get update –fix-missing